# How to Send Javascript as HTML/Text Format in Email using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, email

I have one **Javascript** code that I want to send to user in email using **PHP**. I have to use **"Content-type: text/html"**. When I send javascript in email I want to just display it, don't want to run it. How can I do it.

Here is my code that I am using but it is not displaying in proper format.

```
<textarea style="width:500px;border:solid 1px #666666;height:150px;" readonly="readonly"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://google.com/abc/id=12345></script><script type="text/javascript">document.write(id.responseText); </script></textarea>
```

In email, it is not displaying exactly same as above. Please help me.

PS: http://www.google.com is just for reference, I am using my site address there.

Thanks,
Ketan

Comment: While you're on google, look up `why is document.write() bad`

Comment: Just to say that the javascript won't execute for the recipient as far as I know.

Comment: I have to use document.write(), because it is needed to run javascript

Comment: Ok, I got solution. just use htmlentities(javascript_code) and it won't execute and will display as text in email :) . thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got solution. just use htmlentities(javascript_code) and it won't execute and will display as text in email :) .